# PHP profile image upload fails

Tags: php, database

fail profile upload

What causes the upload to fail in this code? I want to upload a file from that path.

```
<?php
$m_seq = $_POST["m_seq"];
$m_name = $_POST["m_name"];
$height = $_POST["height"];
$weight = $_POST["weight"];
$m_number = $_POST["m_number"];
$b_year = $_POST["b_year"];
$position = $_POST["position"];

$m_id = $_SESSION["id"];
$uploaddir = $full_path . "/data/member/" . $m_id . "/";

$target_file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES["m_prof"]["name"]);
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

$sql_img = "";

if ($_FILES['m_prof'] != "") {
    if ($_FILES['m_prof']['name']) {

        if ($m_seq != "") {
            $sql = "SELECT profile_img FROM member WHERE m_seq ='" . $m_seq . "' ";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $del_row = mysql_fetch_row($result) or die($sql);
            unlink($uploaddir . $del_row["profile_img"]);
        }

        @mkdir($full_path . '/data/member', 0755);
        @chmod($full_path . '/data/member', 0755);
        @mkdir($full_path . '/data/member/' . $m_id, 0755);
        @chmod($full_path . '/data/member/' . $m_id, 0755);

        //    echo $full_path.'/data/member/'.$m_id; exit;


        $ext = substr(strrchr($_FILES['m_prof']['name'], "."), 1);

        list($microtime, $timestamp) = explode(' ', microtime());
        $time = $timestamp . substr($microtime, 2, 3);
        $file_name = "PROFILE_" . $time . "." . $ext;

        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file_name;
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['m_prof']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            $profile_img = $file_name;
            $sql_img = ", profile_img='{$profile_img}'";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('upload fail');</script>";
        }
    }
}

$sql  = "UPDATE member SET m_name='{$m_name}', m_nick_name='{$m_name}', height='{$height}',m_number='{$m_number}', weight='{$weight}', b_year='{$b_year}', position='{$position}'";
$sql .= $sql_img;
$sql .= "WHERE m_seq='{$m_seq}'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<script>location.href='./index.php';</script>";
mysql_close($link);
exit;
```

upload fail
What causes the upload to fail in this code? I want to upload a file from that path.

There is a problem uploading your image while updating your profile content. I would like to know why the upload failed.

```
<li><input type="file" name="m_prof" id="m_prof" style="display:none;" /></li>
<li><input type="text" placeholder="Your position" name="position" id="position" value="<?php echo $m_info["position"]; ?>" /></li>
<li class="ofh">
    <p class="fl w30 pr10"><input type="text" name="height" id="height" value="<?php echo $m_info["height"]; ?>" placeholder="cm" class="tc" /></p>
    <p class="fl w20"><input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" value="<?php echo $m_info["weight"]; ?>" placeholder="kg" class="tc" /></p>
    <p class="fl w50 pl10"><input type="text" name="b_year" id="b_year" value="<?php echo $m_info["b_year"]; ?>" placeholder="birth year" class="tc" /></p>
</li>
<li><input type="submit" value="Done" /></li>
```

Comment: You have to use session_start() before $m_id = $_SESSION["id"];

Comment: First of all always format your code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You could use the copy() function :

```
// Will copy foo/test.php to bar/test.php
// overwritting it if necessary
copy('foo/test.php', 'bar/test.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use copy() function. And if the error persist try to check for a typographical error in your codes.